# net::ERR_TIMED_OUT when posting to ACS URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 3d-secure

I'm integrating 3D Secure for a payment gateway and keep getting a timeout error when trying to post to https://dropit.3dsecure.net:9443/PIT/ACS.

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Has anyone else encountered this? Anything i can do about it or is it just my internet connection?

Comment: Hi, did You solve this problem?